# Maven TestNG Selenium How to debug while executing tests from Console

Tags: maven, testng

I am using Maven+TestNG+Selenium+Eclipse IDE. How can i debug code when i run tests from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the below can help, pretty clean instructions which work.. 
http://www.homik.de/think/index.php/2008/07/31/debugging-maven-projects-with-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following:

mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" test
which i lent from the documentation of the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html).